# Convert mysql database to Oracle

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, ddl

I want to convert my MySQL database to Oracle. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958448/convert-mysql-sql-to-oracle-sql). I tried Oracle SQL Developer and watched [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/quickmigrate-085959.html) as well. I downloaded the oracle developer from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index-archive121-097440.html). But there isn't any item called "Migrations" or "Repository" in that tool. I use MySQL 5.5 and oracle 10 g servers.

How do I convert a MySQL database to Oracle? Any working code or useful link would be appreciated. I am familiar with MySQL, but an absolute beginner on Oracle databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The download link you showed for Oracle SQL Developer is very old (V 1.2 from 2007!)...
current version is 3.x from March 2011 - see for download http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

The current version has indeed a Migrations as submenu of Extras... HTH