# How to restore/import a .sql file (MYSQL) into Oracle Database?

Tags: mysql, oracle, import, restore

So far, I am using mysql for my application. In the process of R&D i want to use oracle for my application and see its performance. I have taken dump of existing database and named it "*app.sql*". I want to import or restore the same database into Oracle server. Is there any way to do it? or Any migrating tools exist?

or

Is it possible to convert **.sql** file to **.dmp** file and import to oracle?

i am using ***mysql version is 5.5.31*** and ***Oracle version is: 10g***.

Comment: Oracle now owns both these databases. **google it** although you may have to pay for a click and go solution.

Comment: This may help, **again a quick google** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459336/convert-mysql-database-to-oracle

Comment: thanks for the link.. really helpfull... :)

Answer (score 0):

It happens that the free-to-use (but not open source) [Oracle SQL Developer program](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index-097090.html) is capable of importing MySQL databases into the Oracle table server.

This program is pretty convenient for a new Oracle user; it's pure Java so you don't have to muck about with the laughably misnamed Oracle Instaclient stuff.  No TNSNAMES.ORA required; just connect.

(Be sure to talk to your finance people before you commit to using the Oracle table server.)